# Ubuntu Install And Data Recovery From Windows

Tags: partitioning, windows

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 on a Mem Stick as my Win 7 install has died and wanted to install permanently. There are 6 partitions across the three HDD's and OBV it only sees 4 of them.
All the discs are practically full (apart from the win 7 partition OBV) so I can't back up (Over 1TB of stuff) without buying another drive(s) that I don't need (and can't afford).
Is there anything I can do to keep the data and install? Specifically, and I apologise if this is a dumb question, can you resize the partitions and does this wipe all the data?
I thought just unplugging one of the drives might enable the OPsys to see the other drive, but no. I have only used Ubuntu on a teeny tiny netbook so am something of a Noob when it comes to large drives and files. Pretty sure the only solution is to go back to windows (Aaaarghh) or wait and buy another huge drive and backup, but any help or alternatives are appreciated.
Ta.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying: `I'm running ubuntu 11.10 on a Mem Stick as my Win 7 install has died and wanted to install permanently`. What do you want to install permantly, Ubuntu or Win 7? `Is there anything I can do to keep the data`, `can you resize the partitions and does this wipe all the data?` What do you want with youre data, backup it or wipe it?

Comment: If you have found your answer, please click the check on it to approve it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have Six partition and partition one has windows 7 and some free space

yes you can resize
yes it is safe to install 
it would be safer to remove the other two drives for safety reason

or to be 100+ percent sure,

burn ubuntu on a dics, remove all inter hard drives and install it on a usb drive and boot from usb... install dropbox and other cloud service and back up data

or pay up here on crashplan http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/crashplan.html and backup data from live usb and do all the risky business